# Mongo Db Cluster Transaction

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

With the following code i create some kind of versioning for records and it works fine so far.

db.collection.findOneAndUpdate(

```
   {},
   { $inc: { Version: 1 } },
   { projection: { Version : 1 }, returnNewDocument : true  }
 )
```

But my question is now save that this will also work in mongodb clusters? Does mongo guarantee clean reads in this case?

E.g. i could imagine that someone is talking to a slave and tiggering this function while the functions is a millisecond later running on the master.

Now i need 2 things to be fullfilled

1.) I don't get duplicate versions

2.) the version is in the order the requests were sent

Is MongoDb Cluster meant to make this update transactional over all nodes in the cluster ?

Comment: You are talking about ["Sharding"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/sharding/) so perhaps you should read up on it. Brief answers are "yes" and "yes", and the third is best answered by actually reading the manual section and understanding what "shards" actually are. Which by your question you really do not.

Comment: I talk about the non sharding scenario. Sorry i didn't mention this in my post

Comment: On the scarier side you are even possibly referring to ["Replication"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/replication/) and quite typically and unfortunately missing the point yet again, since this is not a means to "scale" but is rather for "redundancy" though the two are often confused. Also the whole issue wanders wildly "off-topic" for stackoverflow since it's all about database administration and configuration. For which you should be asking on [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com) instead.